# Outline color of the Frame is not displayed in Xamarin Forms Android Project using MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

Currently I am working on a Xamarin Forms Android project using MvvmCross. I have a strange problem regarding the Frame. Whenever I set the OutlineColor, it is displayed only in iOS and not in Android. I've tried with a different Xamarin Forms projects and it is displayed by both platforms without any problems. I don't have any indications why this is happening. Could MvvmCross somehow related with the issue?

Here is a sample:

```
  <core:BasePage
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Core.Base.Views;assembly=Core"
        x:Class="Views.TestPage"
        BackgroundImage="background_secret.png"
        Title="Test">

        <ContentPage.Content>
            <Grid
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Padding="12,20,12,20"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Frame
                    HasShadow="false"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    OutlineColor="#1961ac">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame
                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                Padding="8,4,8,4"
                                HasShadow="false"
                                OutlineColor="#9DB0BB">
                                <Label Text="Test"></Label>
                            </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </core:BasePage>
```

[image: Android page]

[image: iOS page]

Xamarin Forms Version 2.1
MvvmCross Version 4.1

Comment: Could you add the important pieces of your XAML or UI code and a screenshot of iOS and Android? This might help.

Comment: Same issue from my side! any work around for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even i got the same issue, to solve this i have added custom renderer for Frame control.
In framerenderer need to override method Draw and private method DrawOutline as follows,

```
public override void Draw(ACanvas canvas)
{
    base.Draw(canvas);
    DrawOutline(canvas, canvas.Width, canvas.Height, 4f);//set corner radius
}
void DrawOutline(ACanvas canvas, int width, int height, float cornerRadius)
{
    using (var paint = new Paint { AntiAlias = true })
    using (var path = new Path())
    using (Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw)
    using (Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Stroke)
    using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height))
    {
        float rx = Forms.Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
        float ry = Forms.Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
        path.AddRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, direction);

        paint.StrokeWidth = 2f;  //set outline stroke
        paint.SetStyle(style);
        paint.Color = Color.ParseColor("#A7AE22");//set outline color //_frame.OutlineColor.ToAndroid(); 
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

And in another approach you can also consider using the android selector xml of rounded corner as a background resource.
For more detail on this check my blog post: http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/11/xamarin-form-frame-outline-color_21.html

Comment: 2nd option is an alternative right? you create a custom control out of frame. It is not very clear for me.

Comment: Create a custom control for frame and define background resource xml with darker border.

Comment: The second alternative mentioned in the blog worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Suchith answer is correct and solve my problem here, but the `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` is obsolete since the Xamarin version 2.5.

Now, the better approach is using `Android.App.Application.Context` so this is what code should be now.

```
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        DrawOutline(canvas, canvas.Width, canvas.Height, 4f);//set corner radius
    }

    void DrawOutline(Canvas canvas, int width, int height, float cornerRadius)
    {
        using (var paint = new Paint { AntiAlias = true })
        using (var path = new Path())
        using (Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw)
        using (Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Stroke)
        using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height))
        {
            float rx = Android.App.Application.Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            float ry = Android.App.Application.Context.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            path.AddRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, direction);

            paint.StrokeWidth = 2f;  //set outline stroke
            paint.SetStyle(style);
            paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF");//set outline color //_frame.OutlineColor.ToAndroid(); 
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
```

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353986/xamarin-forms-forms-context-is-obsolete) we have a great explanation for why we should use this new approach and why the `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` is obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

MyCustomRenderer, see you ;)

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(YourProject.Droid.Renderers.BorderFrameRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.Droid.Renderers
{
public class BorderFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        using (var strokePaint = new Paint())
     using (var rect = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height))
     {

          // stroke
         strokePaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
          strokePaint.Color = Element.OutlineColor.ToAndroid();
         strokePaint.StrokeWidth = 5;

           canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, Element.CornerRadius * 2, Element.CornerRadius * 2, strokePaint);  // stroke
        }
    }

 public BorderFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
  }
}
```