# Xamarin.Forms: Forms.Context is obsolete

Tags: xamarin.forms

The new obsolete warning in Xamarin.Forms 2.5 really puzzled me.
What context should I be using in Dependency Services, for example, to call GetSystemService()?

Should I store in a static field the context of activity the xamarin forms were initialized against?

Should I override the android Application class and use its Context?

Should I call GetSystemService at activity create and save it somewhere?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I was having the same issue with several `Dependency Services`

## The simplest solution

In a lot of cases for **Single Activity Applications**

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context
```

Can be replaced with

```
Android.App.Application.Context
```

---

## The Background in more detail

`Android.App.Application.Context` returns the global Application Context of the current process tied to the lifecycle of the Application, as apposed to an Activity context.

A typical example of using the Application context is for starting an Activity e.g.

```
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(myIntent);
```

> The general rule of thumb is to use the current Activity Context, unless you need
>   to save a reference to a context from an object that lives beyond your
>   Activity. In which case use the Application context

## Why did Forms.Context go obsolete?

**Xmarin.Forms 2.5** introduced a new "Forms embedding" feature, which can embed Forms pages into Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android apps. However, since Xamarin.Android apps can use multiple Activities, seemingly there was a danger of `Xamarin.Android` users calling `Forms.Context` and in turn getting a reference to the `MainActivity`, which has the potential cause problems.

## The work around

Inside a Renderer you now get a reference to the view’s context which is passed into the constructor.

With any other class you are faced with the issue of how to get the Activity Context. In a **single Activity application** (in most cases) the `Application.Context` will work just fine.

However to get the current Activity Context in a **Multiple Activity Application** you will need to hold a reference to it. The easiest and most reliable way to do this is via a `class` that implements the  `Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks` Interface.

> The main idea is to keep a reference of the Context when an Activity
>   is created, started, or resumed.

```
[Application]
public partial class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
   internal static Context ActivityContext { get; private set; }

   public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer) { }

   public override void OnCreate()
   {
      base.OnCreate();
      RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
   }    

   public override void OnTerminate()
   {
      base.OnTerminate();
      UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
   }  

   public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      ActivityContext = activity;
   }   

   public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
   {
      ActivityContext = activity;
   }

   public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
   {
      ActivityContext = activity;
   }

   public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) { }  
   public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity) { }
   public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) { }
   public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity) { }
}
```

With the above approach, **single Activity Applications** and **multiple Activity Applications** can now always have access to the Current/Local Activity Context. e.g instead of relying on the global context

```
Android.App.Application.Context 

// or previously

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context
```

Can now be replaced with

```
MainApplication.ActivityContext
```

---

## Example call in a Dependency Service

```
if (MainApplication.ActivityContext!= null)
{
    versionNumber = MainApplication.ActivityContext
                       .PackageManager
                       .GetPackageInfo(MainApplication.ActivityContext.PackageName, 0)
                       .VersionName;
}
```

---

## Additional Resources

[Android.App.Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Application+IActivityLifecycleCallbacks/)

[registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks))

Comment: This does not seem to work with CustomTabsActivityManager(Android.App.Application.Context as Activity). Any options?

Comment: @Shubhan cant you just pass in the parent activity?

Comment: Not in my case i have an interface implementation for opening web links. cant send device specific params, Activity in this case.
The option i'm looking at is a static object on my Activity, which is poor design

Answer (score 3):

In the latest scaffold of a new Xamarin Forms solution the CrossActivityPlugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) is referenced in the Android project. So you can use

`CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(myIntent)`