# Can not cast context into activity Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an issue in `xamarin`, and I need some help, please

From `xamarin` tutorial, I wish to launch a phone call thanks to a `DependencyService`.

Here is the service implementation for Android part:

```
 public bool Dial(string number)
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        if (context == null)
            return false;

        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
        intent.SetData(Uri.Parse("tel:" + number));
        try
        {
            var activity = (Activity)context;
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity,
             new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone }, 1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        if (IsIntentAvailable(context, intent))
        {
            try
            {
                context.StartActivity(intent);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The main issue is: I have a revoked permission

> android.permission.CALL_PHONE

. I precise that I have given the permission in the `manifest`. I have read that I need to register in runtime the permission. It's what I'm trying with

```
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity,
             new String[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone }, 1);
```

But I need the curent Activity as parameter and I can't cast the current Context into `Activity`.

Please help me to find where I have done a mistake.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution.

I had to take the context with

var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;

instead of

var context = Android.App.Application.Context;

After that, cast works nicely

Thanks everybody

Comment: Forms.Context is now absolete with Xamarin.Forms version 2.5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353986/xamarin-forms-forms-context-is-obsolete

Comment: Only Forms.Context worked for me, not Apllication.Context.. But it's been deprecated. Is this a bug?

Comment: Casting to Activity from Android.App.Application.Context doesn't work.

Comment: How are you solving it now?

I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(YourActivityName)Forms.Context;
```

for example:

```
var activity = (YourActivityName)Forms.Context;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are in Activity.

You are casting Application context.

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
```

Replace it with below

```
var context = android.content.Context;
```

If you are working in Service then you can ask for permission from where you are calling your service.