# Xamarin: Obsolete Forms.Context and AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-alertdialog, android-context

I used to create it like this

```
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( Forms.Context );
```

And it worked fine. But Forms.Context is obsolete now so I changed it to

```
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( Android.App.Application.Context );
```

Now it crashes with

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

I tried the alternative constructor

```
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Style.Theme_AppCompat_Light );
```

And that crashes with

```
Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

So what context do I pass to AlertDialog.Builder() in XF2.5? I don't feel like installing a 3rd party library for this.

Comment: Try passing in your MainActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a static variable in Main Activity like this

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Instance = this;
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

The reference it in your code like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.Instance );
```

For more details and other ways to achieve this, [see David Britchs blog post](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html)

Comment: Quote from your link: "Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context has been marked obsolete because it was a global static reference to an Activity, which is not ideal." So what is the benefit of replacing one global static with another?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko XF did that because with the old way, you can't be sure if the context was from MainActivity. With this approach, when you want to use Instance, you specify MainActivity.Instance. It seems obvious you target MainActivity and not SplashscreenActivity for instance.
You can find more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353986/xamarin-forms-forms-context-is-obsolete