# Xamarin C# cannot convert c# class to Android.content.context

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i'm trying to test the DependencyService of my app by displaying an alert dialog from an android project when i press a button i created in the share code project.

When i try to set the Context property in the 'AlertDialog.Builder' by entering 'this' in the parenthesis i get this error: "Cannot convert from 'CallDiverter2.Droid.CallDiverter_Android' to 'Android.Content.Context'.

Also the namespace is decorated with: '[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CallDiverter_Android))]' if its matter.

this is the function in the android project i want to call using the DependecyService:

```
public class CallDiverter_Android : ICallDiverter
{
    public void DivertCall(string callForwardString)
    {
        //Divert call code

        //String callForwardString = "**21*1234567890#";
        //Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial); // ACTION_CALL
        //Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(callForwardString);
        //callIntent.SetData(uri);
        //Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(callIntent);


        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
        alert.SetTitle("Title");
        alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");
        alert.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
        {
            alert.SetMessage("This is an alert message");
        });

        alert.Show();
    }

    public void StopCallDiverting()
    {
        //Stop the call diverting action
    }
}
```

How should i fix this so i can successfully test the dependencyService?

Comment: `new AlertDialog.Builder()` constructor requires a `Android.content.context` as a first parameter, while you passing `this`, thich is not a context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a single activity application you could probably just get away with passing in

```
Android.App.Application.Context
```

Eg

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

However to get the current Activity Context in a Multiple Activity Application, then you will need to keep track of it

See this answer for how to keep track of the current context

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47363378/1612975

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to display thet alertDialog when i press the button. Although it says now that the 'Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context' is obsolete

Comment: @MetaDude Sorry `Android.App.Application.Context` try this

Comment: @TheGenetral Dont be its cool. I tried it but it threw an uncaught exception: 'unable to add window - token null is not for an application' error message, and kinda freeze my visual studio. your previous solution on the other hand did work.

Comment: @MetaDude is this a single activity app?

Comment: In single activity you mean single window app? If so, then yes For now there is only one window at the moment

Comment: @MetaDude Android.App.Application.Context should work, and it shouldnt stall visual studio

Comment: Alright i'll try it again. In the meanwhile i get an error in my ViewModel, it enter a breakpoint at the Command in the constructor. Something about 'Error while resolving expression: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Hope it will work after i'll found out how to solve this new problam. Thank you any way!

Comment: @MetaDude for a more reliable way, follow that linq in the answer. also dont be worried about reopening the question if your problems arent solved or asking a new one

Comment: Thank you! I'll sure be doing that if i need to :)

Comment: A little question i just thought about, should've i put this code in the MainActivity class in the Droid project in Xamarin or could i create new class in the Droid project and work on this there?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick in xamarin to do so.
and most people also consider it very handy approach that is

create a static property of your MainActivity Class inside it (Singleton approach)

```
internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
```

Assign this **Instance** object value at the end of the construct of MainActivity like this

```
Instance = this;
```

Now use it like this to get context where ever you need

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.Instance);
```

This works well because most of the xamarin forms app have only one activity i.e. MainActivity

Comment: I tried your solution but when i started the app and clicked the button it threw a bunch of error messages and did not displayed the alertDialog popup.

Comment: will you please share the error you are getting. and how you are invoking DivertCall method

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not work, because your class does not inherit from the Activity/Context class. Therefore `this` cannot be converted to `Android.Content.Context`

Just use `Android.App.Application.Context` to get the current Android Context.

Comment: Hey, i tried this like TheGeneral proposed earlier but it freeze the visual studio and was unable to display the Aler window. It says in the LivePlayer Debug log: 'Unable to add window - token null is not for an application'

Comment: Try calling it from the UI Thread like this `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DependencyService.Get....)`

Comment: I'll try it. In the meanwhile i get an error in my ViewModel, it enter a breakpoint at the Command in the constructor. Something about 'Error while resolving expression: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Hope it will work after i'll found out how to solve this new problam. Thank you any way!

Comment: Good luck, I think you will have to fix the command problem on your own, otherwise open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and fixed it.
This question is pretty old now but I put my insight for any person meeting the issue.

It turns out it did not like me to put my classes to work with SQLite into the `AppName.Android.Persistance` namespace instead of `AppName.Droid.Persistance`.

I just put Droid back and the error has gone.